# user_save does not save data

Tags: 7, users

if a user changes his email address, I want him to lose a specific role (if he had that role in the first place). To make matters more complicated, we have the "email confirm" module enabled and this bitchy little module uses user_presave() in a way that leaves no traces of an email change when it is called during the edit of a profile. So I wrote a module and gave it weight -1 to make sure it gets a chance to compare $edit->mail to the users current mail before "email confirm" begins to work.

My code looks like this (version with a lot of debug statements that will be removed in the live environment):

```
function xyz_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (!empty($edit['mail']) && (!empty($account->mail) && $account->mail != $edit['mail']) && !user_access('administer users') && !drupal_installation_attempted()) {
    // remove xyz role if the users changes his email address
    $user = user_load_by_mail($account->mail);
    $role = user_role_load_by_name('xyz');
    if (array_key_exists($role->rid, $user->roles)){
      drupal_set_message('In if-clause.');
      $return1 = print_r($user->roles, TRUE);
      drupal_set_message($return1);
      $user2 = user_save($user, array('roles' => array_filter($user->roles, function($item) use ($role) {return $item != $role->name;})));
      $user3 = user_load_by_mail($account->mail);
      $return2 = print_r($user3->roles, TRUE);
      drupal_set_message($return2);
      if (!$user2){
        drupal_set_message('User_save() failed.');      
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

If I log in with a test user that has role xyz and change his email address at the "edit profile" site, i receive these status messages:

- In if-clause.
- Array ( [2] => authenticated user [5] => abc [8]
  => xyz )
- Array ( [2] => authenticated user [5] => abc )

The debug messages tell me that:

1. It has been found out, that the user has the role xy and therefor the if-clause was entered.
2. Before the call to user_save(), the user had the role xyz
3. After the call to user_save(), the user was freshly loaded and he did not have the role xyz anymore

Yet despite all this, the user does not lose the role, no matter how often I change the email address or flush the cache.

My question now is: What the hell?

Using user_save() in the user_presave() function seems to be odd, but when I put the $roles array in $edit without the xyz-role, I receive pdo exception that states, that the roles are already set for this user.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.

```
function xyz_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (!empty($edit['mail']) && (!empty($account->mail) && $account->mail != $edit['mail']) && !user_access('administer users') && !drupal_installation_attempted()) {
    $role_position = array_search('xyz', $account->roles);
    // Use !== or === here since $role_position may be zero or FALSE
    if ($role_position !== FALSE) {
      unset($account->roles[$role_position]);
      $edit['roles'] = $account->roles;
    }
  }
}
```

I still do not know what's wrong with the code in the initial post, but whatever...